# Dark mode toggle with Tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, tailwind-css

I have a problem with a toggle interaction button for change the theme style.
I use the tailwind framework for styling and i set all element with the dark option. I create the function for set the theme to the user system preferences and i crate a function for change the theme with the toggle button trigger. I have the same element in two diferent template of my wordpress theme, in the header.php and the footer.php. The toggle in the header works but the button in the footer themplate dosen't work.

```
<div class="hidden dark:flex">
 <p class="text-gray-100 mr-2">Go light</p>
 <img class="sun cursor-pointer" src="/img/icon/mdi_sun.svg" alt="light_mod">
</div>
<div class="flex dark:hidden">
 <p class="mr-2">Go dark</p>
 <img class="moon cursor-pointer" src="/img/icon/mdi_moon.svg" alt="dark_mod">
</div>
```

This is the toggle button for change the style

```
// Dark mode
const sunIcon = document.querySelector(".sun");
const moonIcon = document.querySelector(".moon");

const userTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
const systemTheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

const iconToggle = () => {
    moonIcon.classList.toggle("display-none");
    sunIcon.classList.toggle("display-none");
};
const themeCheck = () => {
    if (userTheme === "dark" || (!userTheme && systemTheme)) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
        moonIcon.classList.add("display-none");
        return;
    }
    sunIcon.classList.add("display-none");
};

const themeSwitch = () => {
    if (document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")) {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
        iconToggle();
        return;
    }
    document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    iconToggle();
};

sunIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    themeSwitch();
});
moonIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    themeSwitch();
});

themeCheck();
```

This is the Javascript function for check the user preferences and change the style.

I try to remove the toggle from the header template and the toggle in the footer works but i don't understand why it works only in the first template i call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with the dark mode toggle in your WordPress theme may be related to the fact that the JavaScript code you provided is running before the DOM elements in the footer are available. When you run your JavaScript code, it might not be able to find the .moon and .sun elements in the footer, leading to the toggle not working in the footer but working in the header.

To ensure that your JavaScript code works for both the header and footer, you need to make sure that the DOM elements are available before you attach the event listeners to them. You can achieve this by placing your JavaScript code at the end of your HTML, just before the closing  tag, or by running your JavaScript code after the DOM has fully loaded using an event listener like DOMContentLoaded.

Here's how you can modify your JavaScript to ensure it works for both the header and footer:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Dark mode
    const sunIcon = document.querySelector(".sun");
    const moonIcon = document.querySelector(".moon");

    const userTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    const systemTheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

    const iconToggle = () => {
        moonIcon.classList.toggle("display-none");
        sunIcon.classList.toggle("display-none");
    };
    const themeCheck = () => {
        if (userTheme === "dark" || (!userTheme && systemTheme)) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
            moonIcon.classList.add("display-none");
            return;
        }
        sunIcon.classList.add("display-none");
    };

    const themeSwitch = () => {
        if (document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")) {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
            localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
            iconToggle();
            return;
        }
        document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
        iconToggle();
    };

    sunIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        themeSwitch();
    });
    moonIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        themeSwitch();
    });

    themeCheck();
});
```

By wrapping your JavaScript code in the DOMContentLoaded event listener, you ensure that it will execute after the DOM has fully loaded, making it work for elements in both the header and footer templates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried wrapping the functions in the DOMContentLoaded event listener but I still have the same problem. Unfortunately both putting the script in the footer.php in closing to the document and calling the js file from functions.php can't solve the problem.